# width not applying for text area MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

The  width isnt setting for the textarea control. It sets for the other controls. Could somebody tell me why isnt the width applying for text area

For example

[image]

**Setting border to solid for col-md-6**

[image]

```
 <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:100%" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectSummary, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ProjectSummary, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", rows = "3", style = "max-width:100%" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectSummary, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: for textareas in html you don't need the width but columns to set the width of it...

Comment: if i remove the width, I dont see any difference

Comment: a textarea instead of "style='width: 100%;'" will need the attribute "columns = 100" like you have used for the rows. The problem is finding the width you need...

Comment: I don't know if there is another way of changing the width but I know that the style won't matter for a textarea..

Comment: @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ProjectSummary, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", columns = "20"} })

Comment: I did the above and no difference

Comment: sorry it's cols instead of columns...

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Comment: @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ProjectSummary, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", cols = "50" } })

Comment: No difference again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140185/discussion-between-kathara-and-tom).

Comment: @Kathara: None of that is true. You can very much employ style on a textarea and `width` can indeed control the width of it, regardless of what is set for `cols`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt yes I figured that out later as well (see chat). I only remembered having a problem setting the width of a textarea myself some time ago and I used cols then... Tom has already resolved the problem though by eliminating some css-code... :) Thanks for the clarification though :)

Answer (score 0):

The *real* width is the width the textarea has. The `col-md-6` will make it that wide. The problem is that the container you're applying the border to does not actually constrain the textarea. If I understand you correctly that you're applying the border to the div with the `col-md-6` class, that could very well be your issue. The grid classes that Boostrap employ various width, margin and padding settings to construct a grid that is as close to cross browser as possible, and applying actual visible style to them almost always causes weirdness like this. Instead, wrap your textarea with another div and apply the border to that:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="my-awesome-border">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ProjectSummary, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", rows = "3", style = "max-width:100%" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectSummary, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Long and short, you should always avoid adding additional style to anything with Bootstrap's grid classes (col-*, row, etc.).